# jquery buttonset reverting to radio button list when page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Basically I have the code below and every time the page refreshes, the buttonset reverts back to looking like radio buttons. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".filter_type" ).buttonset();
});
</script>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnTimeRange" class="filter_type" name="filter_type"   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="TimeRange" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Today</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">MTD</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for TimeRange (OnSelectedIndexChanged="TimeRange")?

Comment: What you mean by 'every time the page refreshes'? Is it on radio-button change?

Comment: I am not getting any errors on my end.  Try removing '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />' and tell me if that does it.

Comment: Dom, the code for TimeRange just changes the filter type to my data. Removing "<link rel="stylesheet..." didn't work.

Comment: When I click on a button, the whole page refreshes with different data. yes it is on radio-button change.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your asp code as follows (notice the tag `style="display:none"`)

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnTimeRange" class="filter_type" Style="display:none" name="filter_type"   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="TimeRange" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Today</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">MTD</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then use `$( ".filter_type" ).show();` in jQuery as below

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".filter_type" ).buttonset();
    $( ".filter_type" ).show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that just makes the radio button disappear. I need it to keep the styled buttons before and after the refresh.